# How this Facebook API Program Capture Visitors Name and Email without Permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I wonder How this Facebook API Program Capture Visitors Name and Email without Permission.  I visited a Facebook page today and found that my name and email automateically appear when I click on the post image.  I guess they are doing it with the latest Facebook SDK.

This is [the post I am referring to](https://web.facebook.com/connectio.io/posts/806522002806840).

This is [the page about their API Script](http://tinyurl.com/zjx8g7y).

Can anyone tell me where I can setup the same using PHP. I could not locate any information in Facebooks developer page.  Highly appreciate your feedback.

Ishaq.

Comment: Sorry, I made a Mistake, the URL of the API Script page is this: http://tinyurl.com/WhatTheHeck9

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Lead Ads, the docs are full of example code:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/v2.5
- https://www.facebook.com/business/help/397336587121938/